# SaveAs function when saving to excel from Python

Tags: xlsx, xlrd, xlwt, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I know openlyxl ,  xlrd , xlwt, etx have a save method. But I was wondering if they have a save as method. So I want it to open an existing workbook, edit it, but then do a save as therefore leaving the original excel file intact and saving the original with modifications I made in a different location.

Answer (score 2):

With openpyxl you must always specify the name of the file that you are saving the workbook as.